# How to use more than one Compute methods in ForkJoin Framework of Javaello

Tags: java, parallel-processing, fork-join

I need a simpler problem to solve. I need to solve the parallel summation of 1000 random X values and 1000 random Y values. I am using Parallel ForkJoin framework of java. With the the usage of single compute method, it's not possible to compute the summation of X values and Y values in completely different routes.

More over I need to calculate Sum of X * Y. i.e Σxiyi BUT X values traversed by one single thread assigns a separate task, and Y is inserted into threadpool as separate task. So how is it possible to multiply both X and Y values simulatanouesly i.e X * Y ==> (X = 100, Y = 150)?
First Thread is operating on X and second on Y.

## Code:

public class RegressionLineForkJoin
{

```
//private static final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool( 2 );         // use only 2 processors

private static Random r = new Random( );    
private static final int NR_OF_VALUES = 1000;      // X & Y VALUES
private static final int THRESHOLD = 100; // need to calculate Threshold value.

    private static class RegressionLineForkJoinTask extends RecursiveTask<Integer>
    {
        private int m_Start;
        private int m_End;

        public RegressionLineForkJoinTask(int a_start,int a_end)
        {
            this.m_Start = a_start;
            this.m_End = a_end;
        }
        public Integer compute()
        {       
            Integer Sum = 0;
            if(this.m_End - this.m_Start < THRESHOLD)
            {
                calculateSum(this.m_Start,this.m_End);
            }
            else
            {
                int split  = (this.m_Start + this.m_End)/2;

                RegressionLineForkJoinTask oRegressionLineTask_1  = new RegressionLineForkJoinTask(this.m_Start , split);
                RegressionLineForkJoinTask oRegressionLineTask_2  = new RegressionLineForkJoinTask( split+1 , this.m_End);

                // Invoke the tasks in parallel 
                invokeAll(oRegressionLineTask_1,oRegressionLineTask_2);

                Sum += oRegressionLineTask_1.join(); 
                Sum += oRegressionLineTask_2.join();

                //Sum

            }//end of else
            return Sum;
        }
        public static void main(String[ ] args)
        {
            RegressionLineForkJoinTask oRegressionLineForkJoinTask_X = new RegressionLineForkJoinTask( 0,NR_OF_VALUES );
            RegressionLineForkJoinTask oRegressionLineForkJoinTask_Y = new RegressionLineForkJoinTask( 0,NR_OF_VALUES );

            Integer Sum_X_Values =  forkJoinPool.invoke(oRegressionLineForkJoinTask_X);
            Integer Sum_Y_Values =  forkJoinPool.invoke(oRegressionLineForkJoinTask_Y);

            System.out.println("in main after forkjoin.invoke()");
        }
        private static double nextRandomFunctionValue(int a_startInex,int a_endIndex)
        {
            double randomValue = 0.0;
            randomValue = a_startInex + ( a_endIndex - a_startInex ) * r.nextDouble( ); 

            return randomValue;

        }//end of nextRandomFunctionValue
        private static double  calculateSum(int a_startIndex, int a_endIndex)
        {
            double sumValue = 0.0;
            double RandomeValue = 0.0;

            for(int index = a_startIndex; index< a_endIndex; index++)
            {                   
                RandomeValue = nextRandomFunctionValue(a_startIndex,a_endIndex);
                sumValue += RandomeValue;

            }//end of for
            return sumValue;
        }       
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should have your 2 int arrays `xs` and `ys` created outside your tasks and given as parameters on your tasks. So your constructor

`RegressionLineForkJoinTask(int a_start,int a_end)`
would be
`RegressionLineForkJoinTask(int a_start,int a_end, int[] vector)` with vector being `xs` or `ys`.
They would use `vector` that way:

```
public Integer compute() {       
    int sum = 0;
    if(this.m_End - this.m_Start < THRESHOLD) {
       for (int i = this.m_Start; i < this.m_End; i++)
         sum += this.m_vector[i];
    } /* else split task as before */
}
```

Then on the same basis you can have a `ProductRecursiveForkJoinTask` working with two vectors with this constructor:
`RegressionLineForkJoinTask(int a_start,int a_end, int[] vectorA, int[] vector B)`

with this compute method:

```
public Integer compute() {       
    int sum = 0;
    if(this.m_End - this.m_Start < THRESHOLD) {
       for (int i = this.m_Start; i < this.m_End; i++)
         sum += this.m_vectorA[i] * this.m_vectorB[i];
    } /* else split task as before */
}
```